# How to determine the end of a SMTP and POP response?

Tags: java, sockets, smtp, pop3

I am reading character by character of a socket response in a BufferedReader written from a socket that I am connecting to a SMTP and POP server. But how do I know if I have read until the end of the response to avoid having the `read()` to hang for reading beyond what the server responded? The following code is how I am reading from the BufferedReader:

```
boolean endOfResponse = false;
while(!endOfResponse) {
    c = in.read();
    if ((c >= 32 && c < 127) || c == '\t' || c == '\r' || c == '\n') { 
        response.append((char)c);
        //The following check has a problem: If the response has multiple lines, the other lines will not be read.
        if(c == '\n') endOfResponse = true;
    }
}
```

For instance, in POP, when I do a `LIST`, the response ends with a `.`. But in SMTP, when I do a `EHLO`, it doesn't give clear indication of when the response has ended.

The use of `in.read() == -1`, sadly, doesn't work as it will still attempt to read beyond the responded data and causes the socket to hang.

So, how do I determine the end of a SMTP and POP response? Better still, is it even possible to know before hand how many bytes I should read from the buffer so that I won't even have to check for end of response?

Comment: Are you aware that JavaMail exists, implementing all those protocols and providing a layer of abstraction above them? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html. Even if you don't want to use it, it's open-source, so you might want to see how it works internally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 2 protocols are different but both are sending messages that end with a newline. With SMTP, you read 1 line at a time (ending with \n), each line you read should start with 3 numbers, then either a space or a '-', if it's a space, then that's the end of the server's response, if it's a '-' (like `250-VRFY` which is what you'd get if you opened up with an EHLO, prompting the server to respond with a list of extended ESMTP commands) then you need to read another line.

With POP3, I believe it depends on the command that you issue. Something like USER or PASS gives you a '+' or '-' response (followed by a code and some text). A command like LIST gives you a '+' or '-', and if '+', you get your list of emails, which will end with a single '.' by itself. Each of these responses (as well as each index of an email) will be a line.

You should take a look at [RFC 821 for SMTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) and [RFC 1939 for POP3](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt) to get a detailed description of the protocols

Comment: So in POP, different commands have different endings? For LIST and RETR, they have a `.` for an end. But for certain commands like USER and PASS, the response doesn't end with a `.`. So in my code, I have to differentiate the different commands and cannot have a generic way of reading the response for all commands?

Comment: Yeah, you need to know whether you are expecting a multiline response with POP3. For instance, if you issue a LIST you must read until you get a "." on a line by itself. Even if there's nothing to list.

Comment: Jordan Stewart posted the more up to date RFC.

Answer (score 4):

In SMTP the end of a response from the server side of the transaction can be determined by looking at the character after the response code: it's a '-' after the status code on every line of the response except for the last line--

```
Client: EHLO my.mailserver.com
Server: 123-This is a
Server: 123 Multi-line response
```

So, for SMTP (I haven't dealt with POP before but it sounds like you've worked that one out!), you'll need to check for the presence of this '-' character after the status code to determine if there are more lines in the response.

The current SMTP RFC (5321) documents this: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321  (e.g. page 32)